# Delete an EditView when button is clicked

Tags: java, android

In functions `delemaileditview()` and `delphoneeditview()` are supposed to delete existing `Editview` but there is unknown issue that stop the application

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Contact> contact;
    Contact currentcontact;
    EditText nameArea,emailArea,phoneArea;
    int emails=0;
    int phones=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nameArea=findViewById(R.id.name_area);
        emailArea=findViewById(R.id.e1);
        phoneArea=findViewById(R.id.p1);
        contact=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void buttonclick(View v){
        if(v.getId()==R.id.addemail){
            createemaileditview();
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.addphone){
            createphoneeditview();
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.save){

        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.cancel){
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.delemail){
            delemaileditview();
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.delphone){
            delphoneeditview();

        }
    }
    protected void delemaileditview(){
        EditText v = findViewById((R.id.e1+emails));
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        emails--;
    }
    protected void delphoneeditview(){
            EditText v = findViewById((R.id.p1+phones));
        ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).removeView(v);
        phones--;
    }
    protected void createemaileditview(){
        Context context=getApplicationContext();
        EditText designation1 = new EditText(context);
        designation1.setSingleLine(true);
        designation1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
        designation1.setPadding(14,30,14,30);
        designation1.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.editview));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.e1+emails);
        RelativeLayout RL=findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
        RL.addView(designation1, params);
        emails++;
        designation1.setId(R.id.e1+emails);
        designation1.setHint("email "+(emails+1));
    }
    protected void createphoneeditview(){
        Context context=getApplicationContext();
        EditText designation1 = new EditText(context);
        designation1.setPadding(14,30,14,30);
        designation1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
        designation1.setSingleLine(true);
        designation1.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.editview));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.p1+phones);
        RelativeLayout RL=findViewById(R.id.parentLayout1);
        RL.addView(designation1, params);

        phones++;
        designation1.setId(R.id.p1+phones);
        designation1.setHint("phone no "+(phones+1));
    }


}
```

Comment: The "unknown issue" part of your question could be easily solved by getting a stacktrace.

Comment: Also, even without a log I can see a glaring issue. You can't add to View IDs, like you're doing. They're not necessarily generated sequentially.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The code you provided sets `EditText` visibility to `Gone` however, pasting logcat and editing your question with it will help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `HashMap` to store the views you wish to remove.

For example for the email views:

```
HashMap<Integer, View> emailMap = new HashMap<>();
int emailIndex = 0;

protected void delEmailEditView(){
    if(emailMap.size() <= 0) return;
    View v = emailMap.remove(emailIndex);
    if(v == null) return;
    ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).removeView(v);
    emailIndex--;

    // Get rid of any resources allocated to the view
    v = null;

    // If you just want to make it GONE
    //View view = emailMap.get(emailIndex);
    //view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

protected void createEmailEditView(){
    Context context=getApplicationContext();
    EditText designation1 = new EditText(context);
    designation1.setSingleLine(true);
    designation1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    designation1.setPadding(14,30,14,30);
    designation1.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.editview));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.e1+emails);
    RelativeLayout RL=findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    RL.addView(designation1, params);

    emailMap.put(emailIndex, designation1);
    emailIndex++;
    designation1.setHint("email " + emailIndex);
}
```

You could do analog for Phone `EditText` views.

---

Please be aware that I could not help myself, but to change the method names to more closely reflect the Java naming convention. I suggest that you adopt the Java naming convention for all your Android projects.

---

Disclaimer:

I did not test this code, so please let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: @Barms  `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.e1+emails);` what do i do with this statement?

Comment: @ZarmeenMustafa :: good catch! I definitely overlooked that. I think the fix is to remove that line and `designation1.setLayoutParams(params)` then just use `RL.addView(designation1);` this should add the view to the RL at the end. An other alternative would be to replace the `RelativeLayout` in your XML layout file with a `LinearLayout`, if that is an alternative you can except. :: Please let me know if the first alternative works, so that I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: i put the existing edittext in emailMap in oncreate() and replaced 
`params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.e1+emails);`
 with
`View v = emailMap.get(emails);
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, v.getId());`